# TensorFlow on Dell XPS 9300

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently purchased a new laptop, and after setting up the environment on pycharm and running a test code i get several warning messages:

> 2020-10-21 16:11:12.065743: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1 2020-10-21
> 16:11:13.068204: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142]
> This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network
> Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA To enable them in
> other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler
> flags. 2020-10-21 16:11:13.098606: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU
> Frequency: 1497600000 Hz 2020-10-21 16:11:13.098991: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x434ae00
> initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will
> be used). Devices: 2020-10-21 16:11:13.099008: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor
> device (0): Host, Default Version

what am i missing?

this is the system configuration

> H/W path       Device     Class          Description
> ====================================================
> system         XPS 13 9300 (096D) /0                        bus            077Y9N /0/1                      memory         1MiB
> BIOS /0/400                    processor      Intel(R) Core(TM)
> i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz /0/400/701                memory
> 128KiB L1 cache /0/400/702                memory         2MiB L2 cache
> /0/400/703                memory         8MiB L3 cache /0/700
> memory         192KiB L1 cache /0/1000                   memory
> 16GiB System Memory /0/1000/0                 memory         8GiB Row
> of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns) /0/1000/1
> memory         8GiB Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
> /0/100                    bridge         Intel Corporation /0/100/2
> /dev/fb0   display        Iris Plus Graphics G7 /0/100/4
> generic        Intel Corporation /0/100/7                  bridge
> Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #0 /0/100/7.2
> bridge         Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #2
> /0/100/d                  bus            Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB
> Controller /0/100/d/0     usb1       bus            xHCI Host
> Controller /0/100/d/1     usb2       bus            xHCI Host
> Controller /0/100/d.2                generic        Ice Lake
> Thunderbolt 3 NHI #0 /0/100/d.3                generic        Ice Lake
> Thunderbolt 3 NHI #1 /0/100/12                 communication  Intel
> Corporation /0/100/14                 bus            Ice Lake-LP USB
> 3.1 xHCI Host Controller /0/100/14/0    usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller /0/100/14/0/4             input          USB Optical
> Mouse /0/100/14/0/5             generic        FingerPrint
> /0/100/14/0/9             multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
> /0/100/14/0/a             communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
> /0/100/14/1    usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
> /0/100/14.2               memory         RAM memory /0/100/14.3
> wlp0s20f3  network        Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless
> Network Adapter (201NGW) /0/100/15                 bus            Ice
> Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 /0/100/15.1               bus
> Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 /0/100/16
> communication  Management Engine Interface /0/100/1d
> bridge         Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 /0/100/1d/0
> storage        SK hynix /0/100/1d.7               bridge         Intel
> Corporation /0/100/1d.7/0             generic        RTS525A PCI
> Express Card Reader /0/100/1e                 communication  Ice
> Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 /0/100/1f                 bridge
> Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller /0/100/1f.3               multimedia
> Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller /0/100/1f.4               bus
> Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller /0/100/1f.5               bus
> Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller /0/0                      system
> PnP device PNP0c02 /0/2                      system         PnP device
> PNP0b00 /0/3                      generic        PnP device INT3f0d
> /0/4                      input          PnP device PNP0303 /0/5
> generic        PnP device DLL096d /0/6                      system
> PnP device PNP0c02 /0/7                      system         PnP device
> PNP0c02 /0/8                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
> /0/9                      system         PnP device PNP0c02 /1
> power          DELL 2XXFW05 /2                        power
> To Be Filled by O.E.M.

Comment: You probably need to enable something in the BIOS

Comment: I have the same warning. As far as I understand - I need to build tensorflow from source to remove them

Comment: well it looks like that the iris chipset would not work for gpu acceleration, since it is only built for nvidia.